# Show a value on a slider with a triangle in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a slider in my view that shows a value on a gradient, however I try to add the triangle and get rid of the grey circle as shown here: [image: undesired view]

here is the code I wrote:

```
Widget buildNutritionalInfoSlider(String category, double value) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 8.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.green,
                  Colors.lightGreen,
                  Colors.orange,
                  Colors.red,
                ],
                stops: [0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0],
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -20.0, // Adjust this value to position the triangle above the line
            child: _buildTriangle(),
          ),
          Slider(
            value: value,
            onChanged: (double newValue) {
              // Handle slider value change
            },
            min: 0.0,
            max: 600.0,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.transparent,
            inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
            label: '$category: $value',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
      Text(
        '$category: $value',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _buildTriangle() {
  return Container(
    width: 0.0,
    height: 0.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        left: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: Colors.transparent),
        right: BorderSide(width: 10.0, color: Colors.transparent),
        bottom: BorderSide(width: 20.0, color: Colors.white), // Adjust the width and color as needed
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I make it look like this:[image: desired design].

I don't understand why the circle is not disappearing because I just want to show the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the thumb shape, you can provide a custom  `SliderComponentShape`. You can use this.

```dart
class TriangleShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(10);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(center.dx - 10, center.dy);
    path.lineTo(center.dx + 10, center.dy);
    path.lineTo(center.dx, center.dy + 10);

    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
 SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    trackHeight: 0.0,
    thumbShape: TriangleShape(),
    trackShape: const GradientRectSliderTrackShape(colors: [
      Colors.green,
      Colors.lightGreen,
      Colors.orange,
      Colors.red,
    ]),
  ),
  child: Slider(
    value: value,
    onChanged: (double newValue) {
      setState(() {
        value = newValue;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

[image]
Adding  custom SliderTrackShape

```dart
///there is a little drag paint issue on both side, you can play with the paint for this,(minimize the width)
class GradientRectSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape
    with BaseSliderTrackShape {
  const GradientRectSliderTrackShape({required this.colors});

  final List<Color> colors;

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2,
  }) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final rect = Rect.fromPoints(
      Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy + 10),
      Offset(parentBox.size.width, offset.dy + 20),
    );

    final itemSize = rect.width / colors.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color = colors[i]
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

      canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromPoints(
          Offset(rect.left + (itemSize * i),
              rect.top + 15), //add some space if needed
          Offset(rect.left + (itemSize * (i + 1)), rect.bottom + 15),
        ),
        paint,
      );
    }
    List<int> division = [0, 40, 100, 160, 220];

    for (var i = 0; i < division.length; i++) {
      //paint text divisions

      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: division[i].toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      textPainter.layout();
      double extraGap = i > 3 ? 10 : 5; //play with this value
      textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(
          rect.left + (itemSize * i) - extraGap,
          rect.top + 30,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement it in the buildNutritionalInfoSlider? I dont have a themedata there

Comment: You can provide `SliderTrackShape` as well.

Comment: The positining of values is not accurate, I asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602074/incorrect-thumbshape-positioning-in-a-custom-slider-in-flutter

Comment: btw did you try with reducing the width of paint?

Comment: it works when i reduce the width but why does it happen?

Comment: I havent checked the main source code, but my assumption is default padding(thumb)