# Incorrect thumbshape positioning in a custom slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom slider with a custom thumb shape as shown here: [image]

The problem is that the position of the triangle is not accurate to the value for example if the value is 0.0 there is still a slider to the right and if i set it to the max value there is more of slider to the left.

here's my slidertheme:

```
  return SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
      trackHeight: 0.0,
      thumbShape: TriangleShape(),
      trackShape: GradientRectSliderTrackShape(
        limits: List.from(limits.reversed),
        isProteinOrFiber: category == "protein" || category == "fibers",
      ),
    ),
    child: Slider(
      value: calculateSliderValue(limits, value),
      max: 1.0,
      onChanged: null,
    ),
  );
```

and the slider code:

```
class GradientRectSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape with BaseSliderTrackShape {
  const GradientRectSliderTrackShape({
    required this.limits,
    required this.isProteinOrFiber,
  });

  final List<int> limits;
  final bool isProteinOrFiber;

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2,
  }) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final rect = Rect.fromPoints(
      Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy),
      Offset(parentBox.size.width, offset.dy + 15),
    );
    final itemSize = rect.width / (isProteinOrFiber ? 2 : 4);
    final dividerWidth = 1.0; // Adjust as needed
    final cornerRadius = 8.0; // Adjust as needed

    for (var i = 0; i < (isProteinOrFiber ? 2 : 4); i++) {
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color = getColorForIndex(i, isProteinOrFiber);

      final left = rect.left + (itemSize * i);
      final right = rect.left + (itemSize * (i + 1));

      RRect rRect;

      if (i == 0 && (isProteinOrFiber || !isProteinOrFiber)) {
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        );
      } else if (i == (isProteinOrFiber ? 1 : 3)) {
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          topRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        );
      } else {
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          Radius.zero,
        );
      }

      canvas.drawRRect(rRect, paint);

      // Draw dividers
      if (i < (isProteinOrFiber ? 1 : 3)) {
        final dividerPaint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.grey; // Divider color

        final dividerRect = Rect.fromPoints(
          Offset(right, rect.top + 20),
          Offset(right + dividerWidth, rect.bottom + 15),
        );

        canvas.drawRect(dividerRect, dividerPaint);
      }
    }

    List<int> division = limits;

    for (var i = 0; i < division.length; i++) {
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: division[i].toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      textPainter.layout();
      double extraGap = i > 3 ? 10 : 5;
      textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(
          rect.left + (itemSize * i) - extraGap,
          rect.top + 35,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Color getColorForIndex(int index, bool isProteinOrFiber) {
    if (isProteinOrFiber) {
      return index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.lightGreen;
    } else {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return Colors.red;
        case 1:
          return Colors.orange;
        case 2:
          return Colors.lightGreen;
        case 3:
          return Colors.green;
        default:
          return Colors.green; // Default color
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see what can cause this issue, I didn't add the triangle code because even when I remove it and show the circle it's still in the same position.